# running android studio project with google glass

Tags: java, android-studio, google-glass

I am trying to run an application built in Android Studio with Google Glass. When I run the application from Google Glass, it starts the application and then blacks out to the start window again. On Android Studio I get the following message:

> 08-07 19:04:19.842  16629-16629/? W/System.err: at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   08-07 19:04:19.842  16629-16629/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>   08-07 19:04:19.842  16629-16629/? W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   08-07 19:04:19.842  16629-16629/? I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 16629 SIG: 9

It also shows;

> com.example.glasspitch(16629)[]DEAD

Comment: It looks like you don't have the correct error message. There should be a log that gives a specific line number and has the package name of your application. If you can find that log it will help us help you a lot faster.

Comment: Its does not have any error. When i run the project it stops execution at the point what i copy pasted

Comment: But this is just the generic system error that will be shown for all crashes. It doesn't help us determine what your application is doing wrong.

Comment: Try to place the offending code in a try-catch block and on the catch block do error.printStackTrace() so you can see where the error originates.  Post that here, and you'll get better mileage.

Comment: This is the log I captured when running in Debug mode:....com.example.glasspitch/com.example.glasspitch.MainActivity.
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -D -n "com.example.glasspitch/com.example.glasspitch.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.glasspitch/.MainActivity }

Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'